# Why phpMailer gives me the error : can't use function return value in write context

Tags: php, phpmailer

I've installed phpMailer 6.5.1 under PHP 7.3.21 (Wampserver).
I've used the example given on their site to send a simple mail and it works correctly.

When I copy both phpMailer and my script on production under PHP 5.4.20, I have the error "*can't use function return value in write context in src/PHPMailer on line 1700*".

That error appear just after including that file.

Thank you for your ideas!

````
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'librairies/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'librairies/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php'; **error here**
    require 'librairies/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
    
    require 'librairies/vendor/autoload.php'; 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION; 
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'host';               //Adresse IP ou DNS du serveur SMTP
    $mail->Port = 587;                          //Port TCP du serveur SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                        //Utiliser l'identification

    if($mail->SMTPAuth){
       // $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;    //Protocole de sécurisation des échanges avec le SMTP
       $mail->Username   =  'user';   //Adresse email à utiliser
       $mail->Password   =  'pass';         //Mot de passe de l'adresse email à utiliser
    }
    
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; //Format d'encodage à utiliser pour les caractères
    
    $mail->smtpConnect();```
````

Comment: You can check the required version of PHP that PHPMailer version in its [composer.json](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v6.5.1/composer.json). It would probably be better for you to either upgrade your production environment or test locally with the same version of PHP

Comment: From their [github's composer.json](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/composer.json): `require": { "php": ">=5.5.0", ...`

Comment: PHP 5.4 should **not** be in use in any production environment. The solution to your problem is to upgrade to a supported version. [PHP Supported Versions](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Answer (score 1):

PhpMailer 6.5.1 is **not** compatible with your server-side PHP version (5.4.2). Either you upgrade the PHP on your server to at least 5.5 or you use a legacy version of PHMailer. See PHPMailer installation notes below.

**PHPMailer 5.2 (which is compatible with PHP 5.0 — 7.0) is no longer supported, even for security updates. You will find the latest version of [5.2 in the 5.2-stable branch](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable). If you're using PHP 5.5 or later (which you should be), switch to the 6.x releases.**

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#legacy-versions